# How to search via production_id?

Tags: python, odoo

I am attempting to get a field from a manufacturing order to a related work order.

I have tried:

```
for record in records:
  if record.production_id:
    so = env['mrp.production'].search([('name', '=', record.production_id)])
    if so:
      record.write({"x_customer": so.x_customer_nick_name})
```

This however does not work, but if I do a search of the actual production ID name for manufacturing name it works as intended:

```
for record in records:
  if record.production_id:
    so = env['mrp.production'].search([('name', '=', record.'Boost/BoMO/73222')])
    if so:
      record.write({"x_customer": so.x_customer_nick_name})
```

I believe this is due to `production_id`, from the raw data I can see it is `[11212,'Boost/BoMO/73222']`.

So I only need the first element, however:

```
 so = env['mrp.production'].search([('name', '=', record.production_id[1])])
```

does not return the string name of the `production_id`. How should I go about getting this data?

Error Code

```
 pobjs = [adapt(o) for o in self._seq]\npsycopg2.ProgrammingError: can\'t adapt type \'dict\'\n'>
```

Comment: it doesn't work because production_id is the id field in manufacturing order and it's an integer not a string, instead of record.production_id you'll need to put record.name to get the name of the MO. I recommend to activate developer mode in order to get right field names just by hovering on them :D

Comment: It's a list of both an integer and a string, I'm talking about work orders production id. I tried record.name, didn't work.

Comment: I think your question is not clear, production_id is a Many2One field which usually holds an integer that refers to the id of the manufacturing order: you can check it here: https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/14.0/addons/mrp/models/mrp_workorder.py#L38
And it's not gonna work because if you are in a work order the production_id is not enough, but you should access the name using the relation through production_id so it should be something like the following: so = env['mrp.production'].search([('name', '=', record.production_id.name)])

Comment: Thank you for the help. I tried again but no luck. I pulled the raw data of the work order with the web API and get back a list ex 'production_id': [10153, 'Boost/BoMO/73222'] not sure. If I just use the integer it works. I ended up using the web API. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wasn't able to find a solution here or on the odoo forums. For anyone else looking for a solution,  I ended up using the web API. I scraped the work orders and the production ID manufacture orders. Built a tuple wrote to WO with a loop.

```
  models.execute_kw(db, uid, password, 'mrp.workorder', 'write', [workorders_id, {
                'x_for_customer': x_customer_nick_name}
            }])
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this if production_id is of mrp.production relation:

```
if record.production_id:
    so = record.production_id
    If so:
         record.write({"x_customer":so.x_customer_nick_name})
```

production_id is a Many2One field to mrp.production, so you can use it to access any field in mrp.production, and in your case you'd like to get the name of the manufacturing order so it should be something like the following:

```
so = self.env['mrp.production'].search([('name', '=', record.production_id.name)])
```

Comment: No go, I get. Thanks for trying.  pobjs = [adapt(o) for o in self._seq]\npsycopg2.ProgrammingError: can\'t adapt type \'dict\'\n'>